# Hover Text only Displays First Word

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display popup text when I hover over some other text.  The popup text will only display the first word.  I am rather new to php and such, so I hope this is not an idiotic question, but what am I doing wrong here?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $description = $row[2];
    echo $description;  //output:  "Get an Automatic..."
    echo "<a title=$description>";  //Hover output:  "Get"
    echo "blah blah blah";
    echo "</a>;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap them with quotes:

```
echo "<a title='$description'>"
```

Sidenote: It's also important that you might get strings like this:

```
Get an automatic test's
```

That will surely mess up that quoting, and terminate it early, might be better to add `htmlspecialchars()` in that case:

```
$description = htmlspecialchars($row[2], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: @Evorlor yeah, that subtle thing is also important. im glad this helped

Comment: Just so you know, it was not really an oversight.  It was just that I did not know String variables needed single quotes around them.

Comment: @Evorlor yes you need to wrapped up with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $description = $row[2];
    echo $description;  //output:  "Get an Automatic..."
    $firstWord = explode(' ',trim($description));
    echo "<a title='$firstWord[0]'>";  //Hover output:  "Get"
    echo "blah blah blah";
    echo "</a>";
}
```

BTW: you have to warp the string in the title attribut and you forgot a " quote at the end

UPDATE after comment:

Yes that could be because you didn't warp the title attribute and you forgot a " quote at the end

So change it to this:

```
...
echo "<a title='$description'>";
...
echo "</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was that I was only getting the first word.  Not that I wanted only the first word.  Sorry for not being clear.